# Cannot get jQuery Resizable API to work on html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, resizable

I don't get what is wrong here.

I am guessing that the jQuery resizable is not compatible with my table because of the CSS? that can't be right. What am I missing here?

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#data_container {
        height: 175px;
        position: relative;

        border: 1px solid #808080;

        scrollbar-base-color: #DFDFDF;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #235A81;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        margin-top: 5px;

}

#data {
        color: rgb(11,63,113);
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 9pt;
        border: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
}

#data th, #data td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
        border-right: 1px solid #808080;
        padding: 3px;
        width: 150px;
}

#data th {
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
        height: 18px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
        border-top: 0px;
}
#data thead tr {
        top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
        position: relative;
}
#data tr.normal td {
    color: #235A81;
    background-color: white;
}
#data tr.highlighted td {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #235A81;
}
</style>



</head>

<body>
<div id="data_container">
<table id="data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <thead>
                          <tr>
                                <th>HEADER 1</th>
                                <th>HEADER 2</th>
                                <th>HEADER 3</th>
                                <th>HEADER 4</th>
                                <th>HEADER 5</th>
                                <th>HEADER 6</th>
                                <th>HEADER 7</th>
                                <th>HEADER 8</th>
                          <tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 1</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 2</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 3</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 4</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 5</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 6</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 7</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 8</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 9</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 10</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 11</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 12</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 13</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 14</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                          <tr>
                                <td>content 15</td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                                <td>content </td>
                          <tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#data tr th" ).resizable({
      handles: 'e'
    });  
  });
  </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the CSS line-by-line to see what could have changed that would make jQuery not compatible with the CSS.

Changed the line from:

```
#data thead tr {
        top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
        position: relative;
}
```

to:

```
#data th tr {
        top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
        position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the widths on the TDs then it works fine for me

```
#data th, #data td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
    border-right: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 150px; <-- Try removing this
}
```

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Also took a closer look and all of the table row tags are not being ended.

Answer (score 0):

You forgott the jquery CSS file :

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I've already made this error :)

Comment: This is correct - this needs to be added to the page. Also, it needs the ID to be on the table itself. Here is a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/33NEE/